# Maximum value of a function given some constraints

Tags: calculus, optimization, constraints

How would one go about finding the maximum or the minimum value of a function given some constraints; Simple functions are easy to deal with, but what piqued my interest was when I thought about functions having variables multiplied and divided by each other. One such example could be :

What is the maximum value of $x^2y$ give the constraint

$$x + y + \sqrt{2x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 }=K(constant)$$

and also $x,y\ge0$.

I'm not sure on how to proceed on this one as I've tried a few methods, like taking $x^2y$ to be different variable and use the second derivative method for finding maximum and minimum values. However, no results have been calculated yet.

Comment: try looking up Lagrange multipliers

Comment: Is there any other way around?

Comment: First, we should notice that the restriction is basically an eppipse. We can rewrite the condition $x+y+\sqrt{2x^2+2xy+3y^2} = K$ by rearranging and squaring as 
$$(x+y)^2 - 2(x+y)K + K^2 = 2x^2+2xy+3y^2$$
which reduces to $x^2+2y^2=K^2 -2(x+y)K$ which can be rewritten as 
$$(x+K)^2 + 2(y+K/2)^2 = 5/2K^2 $$
which is our ellipse.